# Singletons with eager and lazy instantiation

Tags: java, singleton, lazy

I've found more than one implementation of the Singleton Pattern in Java (more like 5-6). I want to know if both of the following snippets of code (written by me) are valid implementations of Singleton Pattern in Java.

```
//Eagerly intialization
public final class LoggerEagerSingleton {

private static final LoggerEagerSingleton logger = new LoggerEagerSingleton();

private LoggerEagerSingleton() {
}

public static LoggerEagerSingleton getInstance() {
    return logger;
}
}
```

```
//Lazy Initialization
public final class LoggerLazySingleton {

private LoggerLazySingleton() {
}

public static LoggerLazySingleton getInstance() {
    return LazyHelper.logger;
}

private static class LazyHelper {
    private static final LoggerLazySingleton logger = new LoggerLazySingleton();
}
}
```

Comment: Beside the technical part: Singelton are *global variables*. Therefore you should **avoid** using the *singelton pattern*. In case you really need a certain class to have only one instance at your programs runtime use other techniques (eg. a feature of a DI framework) to ensure this singularity.

Answer (score 1):

The singleton pattern guarantees that only one instance of a class will be created into the application context.

So, in your code I see that:

- You are create a `static final class`.
- You declare the selfclass propertie as **final**: `private static final LoggerEagerSingleton logger`

Both of these last points are not necessary because the singleton pattern guarantees that just one will be create and nobody could be modify the unique instance of the singleton class.

The singleton patterns suggest the following rules:

- A private construct.
- A Static private property of the self class.
- A Static method to get the unique instance, where it create the instance if it has not been created.

```
 
    public class SimpleSingleton {

        private SimpleSingleton logger;

        private SimpleSingleton() {

        }

        public static SimpleSingleton getInstance() {

            if(logger == null)
                logger = new LoggerEagerSingleton();

            return logger;
        }
    }
```

As you can see the property `logger` is create in the static method `getInstance()` and no other methods give access or alter this property, and the method give you a way to get the unique instance of the class.

So if you apply these rules, your classes could be rewritten like:

```
public class LoggerEagerSingleton {

    private static LoggerEagerSingleton logger = null;

    private LoggerEagerSingleton() {
    }

    public static LoggerEagerSingleton getInstance() {
        if(logger == null)
            logger = new LoggerEagerSingleton();
        return logger;
    }

    //TODO: All the remain methods
    public void method A()
    {

    }

}
```

And it could be used as:

```
LoggerEagerSingleton ref = LoggerEagerSingleton.getInstance();
ref.void methodA();
```

But remember, a patter is a generic design that has been used to solve some issues that are common in several projects. So you can implement the pattern as it is presented or make some modifications without altering the essence of the pattern.

Comment: Beside the technical part: Singelton are *global variables*. Therefore you should **avoid** using the *singelton pattern*. In case you really need a certain class to have only one instance at your programs runtime use other techniques (eg. a feature of a DI framework) to ensure this singularity.

Comment: labelling the `final` keyword as unnecessary is simply incorrect and dangerous advice. Also your `LoggerEagerSingleton` is lazily initialized, which makes it all the more ironic to name it that way ...

Comment: This kind of lazy assignement can provide two instances in a multithreaded system. There are other patterns to create a singleton and the more secure on is the usage of enum for which the uniqe instance is guaranted by the JVM. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26285520/implementing-singleton-with-an-enum-in-java

Comment: @gervais.b what about my version of lazy initialization (see the question of the post)? I think it can't provide more then one instance even in a multithreaded context.

Comment: @ovidiu-miu your lazy version is not lazy. The instance is bound to your helper field that you reference when needed. In fact both of your samples are almost identical except the lazy one that add one inner class without benefits. If you want à lazy one you need the famous 'instance==null' but to removes the multithread risk you should add some synchronisation.   Again for your knwoledge this is fine but remember that the singleton is an antipattern that cause much more than it solve

Comment: @Gervais.b could you tell me why Singleton pattern is an Antipattern?

Comment: @JorgeOmarMedra http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755539/why-is-singleton-considered-an-anti-pattern

Comment: @gervais.b I think that's not true. The inner class technique is inspired from https://goo.gl/BXQIVK.  "The Initialize-on-demand-holder idiom is a secure way of creating a lazy initialized singleton. It takes advantage of language guarantees about class initialization, and will therefore work correctly in all Java compilers and VMs. The inner class is referenced no earlier (and therefore loaded no earlier by the class loader) than the moment that getInstance() is called. Thus, this solution is thread-safe without requiring special language constructs (i.e. volatile or synchronized)."

Comment: @ovidiu-miu for the `LoggerLazySingleton` sample of @jamal I agree, but my comment was about the sample from @Jorge.

Comment: @gervais.b Really? You mentioned my name..
"@ovidiu-miu your lazy version is not lazy. The instance is bound to..."

Comment: @gervais.b I don't agree with you. Singleton is just a Pattern and, as a Pattern, it depends of who implements it. If you want use singleton with Multithreads you may have some troubles, but is a possibility not a fact. In my case i find that singleton works fine for me when i want to have a Configuration Repository at hand without take care of pass reference between classes, for example. In my experience: PATTER = "A Good Idea Into a Good Design", and as you explain it, ANTI-PATTER = "Good Idea Into a Bad Design or, even worse, without a design."

Comment: @JorgeOmarMedra. Ok. I don't pretend to know everything and to be better than another. My concerns with the _Singleton_ is not about concurrency but design. I worked on an project that was abusing this pattern and it was a nightmare. I don't like it because it is not declarative. I prefer to have a declaration that a class use another that having to open it to discover the relation. In your cases, if the class behavior is influenced by the configuration, then I should comment it in favor of a constructor parameter. But, again, it is a matter of taste. (Note, the link provided is not mine).

Comment: @gervais.b I understood you, don't worry. I know that every solution is succesful if it meets with the business and technic requirements. Also, considere that this question is about an implementation of singleton pattern and my response focuses in the singleton patters that has been presented in the question.

Comment: Step 1: Implement the singleton "pattern" by hand (instead of using DI container). Step 2: Make the singleton hold some state. Step 3: Let the consumers of the singleton modify the state. Step 4: Good luck debugging. Step 5: Add concurrency. Step 6: Leave the project ASAP.  <-- This is not a joke. Hand-made singletons are almost pure evil: super hard to unit test; provide global access to state; hide dependencies between actors that are supposed to be independent; etc etc...